# 'Random' sort order on /review pages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

On SO, at least, there are more than 600 questions/answers to review. I figure that no-one is going to plough their way through all 600, so maybe a default 'random' sort order would be a good idea, so that we get more eyes on more posts.

Just a thought.

Comment: Huh. I figured it already _was_ random. Never bothered to check.

Answer (score 5):

This is now implemented (to be released soon);

- if there are more than (some number, currently 90) matching posts, you automatically get a random sampling; paging and sorting is disabled
- otherwise, you get the "current" view, with paging and sorting

Comment: Is there a way to turn this off for `filter=all`? Over the last month I've spent all my flags slowly working up to page 55. The randomizing of the 300K results has removed all sense of progress.

Comment: @yhw42 hmm - not without a change, unless you filter it by tag first. Let me discuss it internally...

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. It's not that important, so if it takes effort, don't worry. I'll still dig through the old cruft. `:)`

Comment: I also was progressing through items in order, but that was because they were sorted from "worst" (according to the algorithm) to "best".  That meant that I'd find a greater concentration of non-answers at the low end of this sorting, which is where I'd start.  The random ordering means that I now see fewer non-answers per page because there is no preference to the ones that perform worse on the review algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather have the possibility to define **custom search** as in:

```
 /review/first-answers?search=help or thanks or please
 https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers?page=1&pagesize=50&filter=day&search=help or thanks or please
```

Any first-time answer with one of those terms in it is [likely to be suspicious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621017/how-to-make-rounded-corners-on-image-in-uiimageview/4460011#4460011).

Comment: L'un n'exclut pas l'autre :)

Comment: @VonC the webpage link in your profile is broken :(

Comment: @radp: "fixed" (in a way)

Comment: @VonC, this [now works](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions?pagesize=15&filter=week&textfilter=thank)

Comment: @Benjol: excellent. It works for first answers as well: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers?pagesize=15&filter=week&textfilter=thank

Comment: @VonC, it works for any text too...

Comment: @Benjol awesome!

Answer (score 1):

The "newest" sort order should be nearly as good as a "random" sort. Assuming people don't arrive synchronized at the page, everybody should get different newest posts.