# Please allow tag filtering on the new review pages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, review, filtering

I think it could be a good idea to allow tag filtering on the new review pages. There is already a [meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72419/random-filter-on-review-pages) asking for the review pages to be ordered randomly since there are so many to review that some could get lost in the shuffle. I think that allowing users to filter based on tags could help, since a lot of answerers watch their own niche of questions, and would be better able to identify a question as a dupe than Random J. User might.

On a personal note, I think this could be good for *me* since I'd really like a snowballs chance of getting [Tenacious] and [Unsung Hero], and I've noticed that brand new users sometimes don't realize they can vote/accept answers, so if you gently guide them to the accept button but don't mention voting, you can sometimes get a zero-accept out of them. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - look at the side of the review page, with its list of tags. Clicking on any of them will filter the list of posts by tags.

[image: List of tags to filter by]

Alternatively, append the query string `tag=tagname` to your query on any of the `/review/*` pages. For example, [`https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers?tag=jquery`](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers?tag=jquery)

Comment: I notice this sorts results by (votes, -time), but not filtering by tag lists results in random order. Is this intentional? It would be nice to have a way to sort *all* results, otherwise I keep seeing posts repeatedly once I've scanned through a couple pages.

Comment: Works for Tag Summary, but not on the Favorite Tags just beneath them.  If I click a Favorite Tag, I'm sent back to questions.

Comment: Same with the search bar at the top of the page apperently

Comment: This feature is not implemented on the StackOverflow site, at least from my viewpoint.  I can only do "New User" Posts atm, but still no filtering mechanism.

Comment: @GoldBishop This is about the old review system. The new system means that many of these older questions may be outdated.

Comment: @TimYiJiang ty....ill start a new thread