# More aggressive tag match between reviewed question and reviewer activity

Tags: feature-request, tags, review

When reviewing, I was very pleasantly surprised to receive questions that match my most active tags. I suppose it's "by design" and it's a great thing.

But I also receive a lot of questions that really do not match my knowledge (I am a C++/computer vision guy and I am asked to review Json, php, ruby, etc). Some are easy to interpret - they are plain crap, but others need some sort of knowledge in the area to make a clear judgement. Especially the "Suggest improvement" part is compromised.

So, I suggest to limit more aggressively the questions whose tags do not match the reviewer's expertise.

I see other were concerned about the topic, on both pro and contra arguments

[Please allow tag filtering on the new review pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72420/please-allow-tag-filtering-on-the-new-review-pages)

and

['Random' sort order on /review pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72419/random-sort-order-on-review-pages)

But I think that a good formula would be a "biased random order" towards the implicit user preferences. It should limit the "Not sure" clicks my a measurable amount.

**Edit**

To make a clear distinction between the related questions/requests that handle manual sort by tags, I am talking about **automatic filtering** based on reviewer's most active tags.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139588/160003)

Answer (score 1):

Related non-duplicate questions:

- [Allow us to filter Suggested Edits and Review section by tag](/q/125169)
- [Review Queues and Ignored Tags](/q/178378)

While the answer to the first of those is helpful (filter by up to three specific tags), I would like to see a more automatic approach match reviewers to the questions most within their competence.  I believe it should be possible to use the reviewer's favourite and ignored tags, and any tags for which they have badges, to pull 'their' reviews out of the queue.

We'd want to prevent unpopular topics from sitting unreviewed for ever, of course, so a measure of the 'age' of each review is still relevant (and reviewers won't get *only* matching reviews).

---

What I'd like would be for each review task to be (nominally, at least) given a **score** for that reviewer, which is a weighted combination of the scores for

1. Position in the review queue
2. Tags for which the reviewer has badges (additionally weighted for the badge level)
3. Tags that are in the reviewer's favourites list
4. Tags that are in the reviewer's ignored list

That score would then be used to determine the order in which pending reviews are presented.

---

I think that would be an improvement on the current system in these ways:

- It wouldn't require reviewers to be aware of, and to keep updated, the review filter.
- It could take into account more than just three tags (assuming enough computing resource to do so)
- It would never give up when there are no matching reviews
- It can take into account *all* the tags of the question
- It would apply to all review queues