# Allow direct linking to a filtered /review queue

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

I'm really missing the ability to give folks an easily-digestible chunk of the close review to chew on by simply handing them a link to the pending review items in their favorite tag. This was possible before last year's redesign, but it got dropped when the UI changed.

As I recall, the hope at the time was that the backlog would drop low enough to where filtering wasn't really necessary or effective... That didn't happen.

In addition, there was some concern that, because filter preferences are "sticky", it would cause confusion by changing folks' preferences without them realizing it.

That's a legitimate concern. However, it's also an issue with linking to filtered *question* views (which is possible today) and frankly I think the benefits outweigh the concerns.

Please let me hand folks a link such as https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=winapi or https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-type=off-topic and have it actually apply that filter to the items they then see for review.

Comment: Yes yes yes yes! (I hope this is an announcement post)

Comment: Are you saying that the fact that these links would change someone's permanent preferences is something that should also be changed, along with this proposal, or that such an issue isn't worth declining this feature, but that these links would in fact change the user's permanent preferences?

Comment: It's actually possible to do this without changing preferences, @Servy IIRC, it takes a POST request to change them right now, so a system that preserved (and used) a querystring as an override would suffice to prevent confusion here - but if that's not feasible to implement at this time, *I still want this.*

Comment: @Shog9: In which case, I don't want it. If it didn't change my preferences, I would.

Comment: Not an announcement, @Undo - this is just an expedient way for me to get a feature-request into the system before a deadline... (which is 6 minutes away)

Comment: Hopefully related - [easy close review queue filtering interface](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202261/easy-close-review-queue-filtering-interface)?

Comment: The review queues are already filtered in ways that user preferences do not take into account, such as not showing people their own posts for review.  This change would merely put the questions in the reviewer's top tag(s) at the front of the line, which makes a whole lot of sense.

Comment: According to [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75952/192154), `tag=tagname` in the URL should already work.

Comment: It *did* work, @Izzy - then we broke it.

Comment: Oh, *that's* what the first paragraph meant. Who planned that? I mean, so this should implicitly count as a request to fix it? It has my vote then – with an adjustment to the "sticky" part: the "targeted page(s)" should provide a way to "unsticky" it, and restore the "previous stickies" (if any). Alternatively, the filters shouldn't get "real sticky", but simply handed-through via URL parameters; thus the "previous set" could be restored by simply remove those parameters (or closing the browser tab/window).

Comment: This is how it has now been implemented, @Izzy.

Comment: What do you mean it stopped working, @artless?

Comment: I use the three tags 'arm', 'embedded', and 'linux-kernel'.  There are close questions, I see when reviewing the tag questions, but they do not show up for me when I do a *close review* with this filter.  I guess there was a clean-up and maybe the number has went down recently?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=arm http://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=embedded http://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=linux-kernel @artlessnoise?

Comment: Because I stupidly left the review ID on those URLs, @artless. Try 'em again. The queue will filter out things *you've voted on*, but otherwise viewing them won't exclude them from being reviewed.

Answer (score 16):

Good news, everybody! This works!

### By close reason:

- [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-closereason=Duplicate)
- [Off Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-closereason=OffTopic)
- [Unclear](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-closereason=Unclear)
- [Too Broad](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-closereason=TooBroad)
- [Opinion Based](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-closereason=OpinionBased)

### By tag:

- [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=recursion)
- [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=objective-c)
- [google](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=google)
- [jquery-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=jquery-mobile)
- [cryptography](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=cryptography)
- [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=javascript)

### By reason AND tag:

[php + duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=php&filter-closereason=duplicate)

### By tag OR tag:

[winapi or pywin32](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=winapi&filter-tags=pywin32)

---

There's no real UI for this right now, but this enables both ad-hoc UIs based on data.se queries and [potential UI enhancements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202261/easy-close-review-queue-filtering-interface/209778#209778) on the site itself going forward.

Oh - and these have no effect on your saved ("sticky") preferences; they only take effect when the querystring is part of the URL. The review queue navigation will preserve the querystring once it exists, but if you navigate back into a queue normally you'll be back to your default or saved preferences.

Comment: Possible next step - have a "permalink" button (possibly on the "filter" popup) so you don't have to manually write some URL to be able to create a link, you can just use the UI and copy the "permalink" URL.

Comment: New browser start page set

Comment: *LOL* and *Yeah!* Works on ASE as well, great! Good job! Now we need shortcuts to those, like `[close:tags=abc]` (working site-specific, of course) #D

Answer (score 11):

Great Idea! Two suggestions to make it *even easier* to find a filtered queue.

### Add it to your favorite tags list on the front page

> [image: Pending Close Votes on Favorite Tags]

<sup>But make it look a bit nicer, please</sup>

Show only to 3k plus users who are committed enough to a tag to have them in their favorites. People are more committed to cleaning up their bedroom than their house, their house than their neighborhood, and their neighborhood than their town (etc.).

Feel free to exclude [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) if they make people cry about high numbers.

### Add a direct link in the Review Queue

> [image: Review Queue]

When someone sees that a filter is already there just for them, and how many pending items there are, they are more likely to dive in and clear something out, and it will also give them a running tally of something they care about and can (hopefully) put a dent in.