# How do I know if a person has added a correct tag to the question in review?

Tags: feature-request, tags, suggested-edits, suggested-tags

While reviewing suggested edits, I come across various posts on which addition/deletion of tags have been made. Some I understand, rest I don't, because I am not a master of every programming language. I usually skip these edits. Should'nt this be made easy for the reviewers someway?

Comment: If you don't, skipping is best. Plenty of other reviewers around, leave stuff you don't know about to those that do. I wish more reviewers did this.

Comment: For some extend you can check the tag wiki and decide. Sometimes it is very difficult, then you can skip

Comment: How do you suggest this was made easier?

Comment: Only yesterday I learned that you can filter the questions by tags in reviewing as well. Very usefull IMO, because you can limit yourself to reviews you are actually interested in or know about. If you don't know if the tag is corerct, then you can skip the review anyway.

Comment: @Devolus I assume [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208287/allow-direct-linking-to-a-filtered-review-queue) is the canonical post for that feature

Comment: @rene, already upvoted it. Thanks for the link. My comment was meant to indicate that if a person doesn't know if a tag is corerct, the question may be unrelated to hiw expertise and thus maybe shouldn't be reviewed in the first place (unless it would be only about tpying or similar untechnical features).

Comment: @Devolus that is a very good point especially the later part, only tagging is challenging sometimes (not formatting, correction etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because you are given a review doesn't mean you need to act on it, in fact, if you aren't familiar we would prefer that you **don't** review it.  There are enough users who are familiar with specific topics, that someone will be able to review it correctly<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> - this is somewhat of a over idealized scenario as many users who don't know will review it anyway, but the fact that you are asking here means you actually care if you are doing the job correctly.

What you *should* do is Skip the review, there is even a button just for that

[image: Screenshot of review with skip button highlight]

And what is even better is if you didn't get that review to begin with.  There is a filter option, that lets you specify up to 3 tags, and you will only be given reviews in those tags.

[image: Filter Dialog]

The filtering options you select will persist, so if you set it once, you will always be given the filtered options anytime you review.

Comment: The review is just not specific to the tags alone. Sometimes they are formatting code, correcting thread titles etc. Would'nt this remove all these questions altogether?

Comment: @DamienJoe yes, the filter would remove any question that has a specific tag **for you**.  Yes you would miss some slam dunk posts that you don't need to be familiar with the concepts to review correctly, but it would also limit the questions to the tags you want to see for posts that do need some experience.  That's up to you, but if you don't want to filter, then just use the skip button (for the record, I use the filter in other queues heavily but rarely in the suggested edits)

Comment: thanks for your detailed reply!