# Allow to filter for more than three tags in the close votes review queue

Tags: feature-request, tags, review, vote-to-close, filtering

I've been reviewing the close votes for some lesser-used tags, and I've managed to review the entire queue for a few of these tags. This feels great!

Now, I'd like to continue monitoring the close votes queue for these tags, but this is made difficult due to the three tag limit in the filter.

Could we have the option to filter for more than three tags?

Comment: You know you can switch to a new set of tags and then back again, right?

Comment: I think this is an edge case that may make sense, but in general you want to encourage users to review fewer tags at once so they can focus on a specific one, or a small set of sets.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I don't buy the focus argument. By default the queue is extremely de-focused by showing all tags. And just allowing more than one tag doesn't prevent people from entering a single tag.

Comment: I regularly follow four tags: java, floating-point, double, and algorithm. I would be more likely to continue reviewing if there were an easy, one-step, method for checking for questions in any of those tags.

Comment: **Bump**. Commenting here just to say this issue still exists for more than one year and a half already.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, I have bookmarked multiple [filtered review queue links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208287/191131) which cover all the tags I'm interested in, and I open them one by one. This is more convenient than editing the filter and it makes sure that I don't overlook one of the tags I want to monitor.

Still, allowing more than three tags in the filter UI or in filtered links would be more convienient.

Example link:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=eclipse-rcp,eclipse-plugin,update-site
```