# How does the /review page work?

Tags: support, review

How do the `/review` pages (for example, https://stackoverflow.com/review) work?

- What actually happens when you click "flag for removal"?
- Is there a limit to the number of questions that can be reviewed?

Related: [Can we agree on a review 'policy'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74194/how-to-review-can-we-agree-on-a-review-policy)

Comment: Please add to this if you know more than I do (which you almost certainly do).

Comment: I think this ought to be in the FAQ.

Comment: Either that, or edit this question to talk about flagging caps instead of the review queues, since it talks about the wrong ones.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Is there a limit to the number of questions that can be reviewed?

Since the review page uses "regular" moderator flags, you are bound by the number of moderator flags you have. Currently, all users get ten moderator flags per day.

Users receive one additional flag per day for each 1000 rep they've earned on the site. They also get one additional flag per day for each 20 flag weight earned, up to 500. Users start at 100 flag weight, so...

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ flag weight    100   120   150   500   740  ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ extra flags      0     1     2    20    20  ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

There is an absolute maximum of 100 flags per user per day, but it has essentially no effect for the vast majority of users (those with under 70k rep).

**Note** that the number of questions you *see* is limited if the [result set is above a certain size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72419/random-sort-order-on-review-pages/79634#79634) (90 elements).

Comment: Aren't extra flags not granted after 500?

Comment: @Hello, you are correct, I'll fix it. Feel free to fix such things yourself in the future. This is a CW FAQ entry, after all.

Comment: Well, I actually wasn't entirely sure.