# Does anyone else find the "flag for removal" wording on /review confusing?

Tags: support, status-completed, review, low-quality-posts

Does "flag for removal" on /review mean flag for removal *from the site?*

I think I have been making a horrible mistake thinking it means **flag for removal from /review**!

If it does mean removal **from the site**, then maybe [as Tim Stone suggested](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/467047#467047), "Flag for deletion" would be less ambiguous?

Am I the only one confused by this?

Comment: +1, good point. I would like a way of removing 'ok' stuff from *my* list, so that I don't have to triage it every time. [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75953/allow-marking-posts-as-reviewed-on-review-and-hide-them)

Comment: Actually, these are both dupes of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74249/the-review-page-needs-to-be-able-to-handle-more-than-just-problem-posts) (@Benjol since Josh will be notified anyways)

Comment: @Pop. Half dupe here, 'cos Josh's real question is about changing the name of the 'flag for removal'. Point taken though...

Comment: @Benjol, yeah, that's why I didn't vote to close this one (but did the other one).

Comment: @PopularDemand Surrrrre, go ahead and claim your post is better and mine is a dupe, I see what you're doing here! (I edited the question to make it less of a dupe)

Comment: You may also be interested in my halfhearted attempt to create [an FAQ entry for the whole `/review` system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74238/how-does-the-review-page-work).

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks @PopularDemand!

Comment: Thanks @JeffAtwood! I think this is an improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would change it to.

```
flag for attention
```

Comment: even better idea! I'll change it to this.