# What does reviewing do?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the /review page work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74238/how-does-the-review-page-work)

I always see the reviewing thing on StackOverflow, but what does it do (for me that is)? Or is it simply a tool to gather all the potential problematic posts and have the review from the community?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written in the tooltip,

> These are the first answers a new user has ever submitted to Stack Overflow.

I think it have 2 goals: first to guide the new users, and to support them, and second - to remove bad answers, that do not fit in QA format. For example, often users post answers, containing additional questions to the OP, and those should be posted as comments (but new user may have no enough reputation to post a comment).

Comment: Questions can be CW as well.

Answer (score 5):

> Or is it simply a tool to gather all the potential problematic posts and have the reviewed by the community?

Pretty much. Not all posts that show up on `review` are *actually* problematic, but the ones that are can be flagged for moderator attention or otherwise dealt with by the community.