# How come my vote cap for "First Posts" is lower than others?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, review

I was reviewing First Posts just now, and I received the following message after my 20th vote:

> Thank you for reviewing 20 First Posts today; come back in 8 hours to continue reviewing.

I see other users, with far lower reputation than me, [voting up to 40 times per day](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats).

Why is it I only have 20 votes?  I saw the [How does the /review page work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74238/how-does-the-review-page-work) question, but the accepted answer there mentions flag weight, and I was under the impression that Flag Weight is gone (since it is no longer visibile on my profile).

**What is the formula that determines the number of First Post votes a person can get per day?**

Comment: What does flag weight has to do with post votes, even if it wasn't gone?

Comment: @Yannis - from the answer in the "How does the /review page work?": `Since the review page uses "regular" moderator flags, you are bound by the number of moderator flags you have. Currently, all users get ten moderator flags per day. Users receive one additional flag per day for each 1000 rep they've earned on the site. They also get one additional flag per day for each 20 flag weight earned, up to 500. Users start at 100 flag weight.`  I was just throwing it out there as a possible reason.

Comment: My guess is that this was just recently added as a result of having so many reviwers that that there isn't enough content for them all to review.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Flag weight was affecting number of _flags_, not post votes, it would be quite unreasonable for your flagging history to affect your post vote limits, they are different things. Also that post is obsolete, it discusses the old `/review` not the current one.

Comment: @YannisRizos - that's great, forget I even mentioned flag weight. We seem to be getting off track here though, I just want to know why my cap seems lower than others.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Did you vote on other posts today, posts that you found while casually browsing the site? And if not, can you vote on other posts now?

Comment: @YannisRizos - I've voted on questions and answers up an down while browsing, I've reviewed and acted on Late Answers, Closed Answers, Low Quality Posts.  First Posts is the only one currently disabled.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Well the 40 votes limit is for voting in general, not just for voting on posts you're reviewing. But you've only casted 22 votes today, so this seems strange.

Comment: I think you get 20 reviews per queue per day period...dunno where that's documented though

Comment: @BenBrocka - then how do some users have 40 reviews? I'm just looking for some official documentation or some sort of consistent behavior.

Comment: Looking at the review stats it looks like some are capped at 20 and some at 40 (with some weird outliers). Not sure then.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We introduced and then fixed a bug over the weekend, which caused a couple thousand erroneous posts to be added to the queue. We usually limit the First Posts queue to posts created within the past 30 days, but that requirement was accidentally lifted for a short while. As a result, the queue size spiked up to around 2000.

Currently, we allow 20 reviews per user per queue per day, but we double this to 40 if the queue size is over 1000. So, the users that reviewed 40 first posts today managed to do so before we fixed the bug.

Comment: Interesting... I saw the queue spike up this weekend, I wondered what that was about.  So some of the people who had 38 or 39 reviews for the day must have been right around the time the queue dipped back under 1000.  Thanks for the update!