# Order review area answers by votes, ascending

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

Looks like [questions in the review tab are already in random order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72419/153691). Could we take it one step further and have that random list of questions be ordered by votes, ascending?

The logic being that questions and answers with more votes *probably* don't need as much TLC as those questions and answers with negative votes or zero votes.

Comment: I've flagged many a answer that had positive votes, up to +3. What does re-ordering them by votes *really* achieve?

Comment: I'm just mentioning a trend in votes --> post quality. Posts with more votes are *more likely* to have fewer quality issues--it's not a hard & fast rule, just an observation.

Comment: There is no relation between votes, and quality of a post. There are high voted posts with a lower quality than posts with less votes. If you disable the random sorting, you can sort posts by their score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's already a very easy way to do this under the **Custom Sort** area right below **Tag Summary**:

[image]

That option will stick, giving the behavior I was looking for.