# Summary tab for review pages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, tabs, summary

On tex.sx, the review tabs that I (>5k user) can see are usually empty. It'd be useful if there was a *summary* tab in the /review section so that we could see at one glance that there's nothing to do.

For the cases in which there are questions to be reviewed listed on the *summary* tab, the reason why they need reviewing would have to be indicated, obviously.

I would assume other smaller stackexchange pages are in a similar situation; and although [stackoverflow certainly isn't lacking material to review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72419/162565), this tab could still be useful for users who'd like some variety in their reviewing.

Comment: Empty review tabs? On a site just shy of 14K questions? What's your secret, TEXopedians?

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox: Hard to say. I like to think the world of TeX and friends is a fairly specialized field, mostly academic, and users tend to express themselves in a pretty structured way (and LaTeX encourages them to do so). This makes the posts pretty good on average. On top, most of our higher-rep users (i.e. those with the required privileges) are quite actively pursuing moderation chores. The stackexchange concept seems perfect for this field.

Comment: Actually, it seems I was exaggerating slightly: Currently, there are four posts to be reviewed :)

Comment: Well, the Programmers.SE review page is empty right now. Let's see how many seconds that will last.

Comment: By default it shows posts for review within the current *day* only. Are you looking across all available data?

Comment: @Yuck If you are asking me, I don't even dare... Just the daily posts are enough, thank you.

Comment: @Yuck: Yes, that's how I found the four posts.