# 'First Questions' and 'Late Answers' review pages change after receiving reviewer badge?

Tags: discussion, bug, review, review-badges

I just received the `reviewer` badge and it seems that the `First Questions` and `Late Answers` review pages have changed. For example; the [first questions review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions) used to show at the bottom of the page:

[image: old]

Since receiving the badge it shows the following at the bottom of the page:

[image: new]

Funny enough the `First Answers` review page still shows the *old* style 'bottom of page'.

I'm not sure if this is by design as I couldn't find any documentation for this change. If it is by design then why doesn't the `First Answers` page have the same style? If it is not by design then there is some kind of bug, where either the `First Answers` page needs to be given the *new* style or both the `First Questions` and `Late Answers` should be given the *old* style.

Comment: I think it depends on the *number* of posts there are to show. With the second example there are "only" 5*15 = 75 posts at most.

Comment: It seems you are right. The bottom of the page depends on how many posts there are. I can't recall having seen the _new_ style before and assumed it be related to the `reviewers` badge. While this still might be true, it could also just have been a coincidence that I visited the pages while the _counts_ for new `First Questions` where reset for this day, resulting in the _new_ style to show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assure you it has nothing to do with the badge. When [there are 90 items or less](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79634) to review for the task, **random mode automatically gets disabled** and the panel begins showing you the page numbers. You can also disable random mode manually, in which case you'd have the following message below that:

[image: Showing posts in order (enable random ordering)]